# How do I find the numeric value in the list by searching for the associated name?

Tags: python

Instead of printing "found", I want to print the associated numeric value

```
def lookupHostGroup(group):
  hostgroups = [
  ['Maas GCP Pod M005', '134'],
  ['Maas GCP Pod M006', '136'],
  ['Maas GCP Pod M007', '135'],
  ['Maas GCP Pod M009', '156'],
  ['Maas GCP Pod M001', '168'],
  ['Maas GCP Pod M0011', '166']
  ]
  
  for hg in hostgroups:
    if hg[0] == group:
      print ("found")
      return hg[0]
  
print(lookupHostGroup("Maas GCP Pod M007"))
```

Comment: Think about it for a minute. Where is the "numeric value" stored? You already have `hg[0]` to get the group name. So how do you access the numeric value?

Comment: The answer to your question, of course, is to change your return statement to `return hg[1]`.  HOWEVER, it would be much smarter to convert that to a dictionary, and let Python do the lookup for you.

Comment: As an aside, this code rebuilds `hostgroups` on every call.  You could pull its definition out of the function.

Comment: Ah figured it out.

def lookupHostGroup(group):
  hostgroups = [
  ['Maas GCP Pod M005', '134'],
  ['Maas GCP Pod M006', '136'],
  ['Maas GCP Pod M007', '135'],
  ['Maas GCP Pod M009', '156'],
  ['Maas GCP Pod M001', '168'],
  ['Maas GCP Pod M0011', '166']
  ]
  
  for hg in hostgroups:
    if hg[0] == group:
      print ("found")
      return hg[1]

print(lookupHostGroup("Maas GCP Pod M007"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def lookupHostGroup(group):
    hostgroups = [
    ['Maas GCP Pod M005', '134'],
    ['Maas GCP Pod M006', '136'],
    ['Maas GCP Pod M007', '135'],
    ['Maas GCP Pod M009', '156'],
    ['Maas GCP Pod M001', '168'],
    ['Maas GCP Pod M0011', '166']
    ]
    for hg in hostgroups:
        if hg[0] == group: 
        return int(hg[1])
  
print(lookupHostGroup("Maas GCP Pod M007"))
```

**This should work out.**

Answer (score 5):

Let Python do the work for you.

```
hostgroups = {
  'Maas GCP Pod M005': '134',
  'Maas GCP Pod M006': '136',
  'Maas GCP Pod M007': '135',
  'Maas GCP Pod M009': '156',
  'Maas GCP Pod M001': '168',
  'Maas GCP Pod M0011': '166'
}

def lookupHostGroup(group):
  return hostgroups[group]
  
print(lookupHostGroup("Maas GCP Pod M007"))
```